# What Ubuntu applications run on the Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, crossplatform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Nexus 7 version of Ubuntu support the same software as the desktop version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215058/does-the-nexus-7-version-of-ubuntu-support-the-same-software-as-the-desktop-vers)

Can we really use all ubuntu applications on nexus 7 when ubuntu core has been installed on it? or should we recompile all apps to arm architecture ?